# How to deploy a database with fulltext indexes with WebDeploy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy a new asp mvc3 website using webdeploy. The problem is that the sql that is autogenerated when creating the package does not contain the fulltext indexes that I have created in the source database.

But all the other tables, indexes, triggers and stored procedures are in the script...Is there something special that needs to be done in order to include the full text indexes?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using the Web Deploy [dbFullSql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569036%28WS.10%29.aspx) provider, try including the `FullTextIndexes=true` setting in your command. **FullTextIndexes** is one of the many SMO [ScriptingOptions Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions_properties.aspx) that you can specify with the dbFullSql provider. You can use this one to have full-text catalogs included in the generated script, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying from Visual Studio or using MSBuild, see the MSDN Deployment FAQ:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#can_i_deploy_the_fulltext_catalog_for_a_database